# TFS Code Review Checkbox

Tags: tfs

I have noticed that there is a checkbox to the right of each file in the code reviews on Team Explorer. I have been trying to research what is the usage of it, but no luck so far. My guess is that is to mark which files have you reviewed so far. Anyone have any insight or official documentation on what is the purpose of these checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely right.

You can put your pointer suspended on the checkbox. Will get a prompt information: **Check this box to mark this item as done** ( Test on my environment VS2015)

Comment: Somehow I completely overlooked the tooltip

Comment: My confusion over the check box tool tip is that it is not clear to me what "done" means. For instance, does it really mean:

1. I've **completely** finished reviewing this file.
2. I've finished initially reviewing it, though I may need to re-review it if the author makes changes.
3. The author or a reviewer has declared this file as needing no further changes.